# using request and beautiful soup module in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My code is very short code but it is giving unexpected error

```
import bs4

url = "https://www."+input("Enter The Name of the website: ")+".com"
req = re.get(url)
html_text = req.text
htmls = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser").prettify()
with open("facebook.html", "w+") as file:
    file.write(htmls)
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tanay Mishra\PycharmProjects\First_Project\Web Scraping\web.py", line 9, in <module>
    file.write(htmls)
  File "C:\Users\Tanay Mishra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 756: character maps to <undefined>```
````

Comment: Please post the exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u200b` means [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) in Unicode. Try to specify `encoding="utf-8"` in open() function. Also good practice is to use `.content` property of `Response` object and let BeautifulSoup to guess the encoding:

```
import bs4
import requests


url = "https://www."+input("Enter The Name of the website: ")+".com"
req = requests.get(url)
htmls = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser").prettify()
with open("facebook.html", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(htmls)
```

Comment: Thanks For The Solution Andrej Kesely.